# SwiftUI: How do I show an alert if a picture is successfully saved or not?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to save an image with SwiftUI. The saving works so far but I want to show an alert if the saving was successful or failed. I already know how to write an alert, but I don't get how to write the information of `@objc func saveError` to the alert. Please help me, I'm a bloody beginner.

This is my Code:

```
class SnapshotSaver: NSObject, ObservableObject{
@State var isPresentingAlert = false
@State var alert = Alert(title: Text(""), message: Text(""))

func saveSnapshot(compressedImage: UIImage){
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(
        compressedImage, self, #selector(self.saveError), nil)
}

@objc func saveError(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if error != nil {
        alert = Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Saving failed"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        print("saving the snapshot failed")
        isPresentingAlert = true
        
    } else {
        alert = Alert(title: Text("Success!"), message: Text("Saving worked"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        print("snapshot successfully saved")
        isPresentingAlert = true
    }
}
```

}

```
.alert(isPresented: self.$snapshotSaver.isPresentingAlert){
                        snapshotSaver.alert
                    }
```

Comment: Can’t you create and show the alert from within saveError?  Or since you are using SwiftUI, set a @State variable that triggers the alert to be shown

Comment: I've just updated the code with @State variables, but it still doesn't show the alert.

Comment: Well `@State` properties are only supposed to be used in a View object, here you should use `@Published` instead

Comment: Oh yes! It works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SnapshotSaver shouldn't have @State properties. Afaik they are only intended for SwiftUI views. Instead make it a normal class that conforms to `ObservableObject`. Then you declare a @Published property for the alerts title and message like this:

```
@Published var title: String = ""
@Published var message: String = ""
```

In your SwiftUI view you declare SnapshotSaver as @ObservedObject:

```
@ObservedObject var snapshotSaver = SnapshotSaver()
```

Now whenever you update title or message in your SnapshotSaver, the SwiftUI view is updated. Just use the `Alert` in your SwiftUI view and grab title/message from your SnapshotSaver :)

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: You're very welcome. If you need more inspiration on that please have a look at my SwiftUI test repo and especially ma ObservableObject: https://github.com/Blackjacx/Emojis/blob/master/Emojis/EmojiFetcher.swift